# flagging consecutive elements in a dataframe and returning a row entry as the index flag. python

Tags: python, function

I'm measuring some voltage drops on a circuit but there's a lot and I want to create a flag showing the date and time of an occurrence when I get 3 or more values that drop below 10 volts.

I  have a csv with the following layout, where V73, V94, V78 and V3 are different circuits and the voltages are listed below each respective column.

```
                     dateTime  V73  V94  V78  V3
0     26/07/2022 14:58:02    10.784     9.218     6.702   18.856
1     26/07/2022 14:58:12    17.432     9.104     7.704   18.530
2     26/07/2022 14:58:22    17.374     9.846     9.178   18.498
3     26/07/2022 14:58:32    17.232    17.354     8.188   18.494
4     26/07/2022 14:58:42    17.066    18.284     9.920   18.216
                  ...       ...       ...       ...      ...
9077  27/07/2022 16:15:00    17.990    17.698    17.092   19.036
9078  27/07/2022 16:15:10    17.076    17.262    17.426   18.158
9079  27/07/2022 16:15:20    17.168    17.774    17.832   19.186
9080  27/07/2022 16:15:30    17.712    17.522    17.658   18.702
9081  27/07/2022 16:15:40    17.272    17.532    17.554   18.386
```

Its probably not the most efficient method so I'm open to suggestions on how to improve it but so far I've done the following. I load everything, find the values and append a boolean array to a new data frame like so

```
V_1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:path\Latest_data.csv')
Vnum = 94
#V_1  = V_1[0:30]
Vnum_name = 'V'+str(Vnum)
VN = V_1[['dateTime',Vnum_name]]

#%%

lwrbnd = 1.01
uprbnd = 9.999
flags = []
for i in VN.iloc[:,1]:
    if i < uprbnd and i > lwrbnd:
        flags.append(1)
    else:
        flags.append(0)
print('flags are as follows', flags)

VN2= VN.assign(flags=flags) 
#print(VN2['flags'[:,1])
```

Then I want to make a function to print the offending entries something like this:

```
def printfunc():
    out=VN2.loc[VN2['flags'],['dateTime',Vnum_name]]
    for x in out:
        if VN2['flags'[0]] == 1 and VN2['flags'[0]] == VN2['flags'[1]] and VN2['flags'[1]] == VN2['flags'[2]]:
            print('dateTime:',out[x].values[0],'\n', Vnum_name,out[x].values[1],'\n')

printfunc()
```

but I can't figure out how to iterate through the entries properly, I'm getting the error

```
KeyError: 'f'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use a library of mine - **convtools** ([github](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools))

Let's assume `tmp/1.csv` contains:

```
dateTime,V73,V94,V78,V3
26/07/2022 14:58:02,10.784,9.218,6.702,18.856
26/07/2022 14:58:12,17.432,9.104,7.704,18.530
26/07/2022 14:58:22,17.374,9.846,9.178,18.498
26/07/2022 14:58:32,17.232,17.354,8.188,18.494
26/07/2022 14:58:42,17.066,18.284,9.920,18.216
27/07/2022 16:15:00,17.990,17.698,17.092,19.036
27/07/2022 16:15:10,17.076,17.262,17.426,18.158
27/07/2022 16:15:20,17.168,17.774,17.832,19.186
27/07/2022 16:15:30,17.712,17.522,17.658,18.702
27/07/2022 16:15:40,17.272,17.532,17.554,18.386
```

```py
from itertools import count
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table
from convtools import conversion as c

voltage_columns = ("V73", "V94", "V78", "V3")

# read + enumerate rows + cast columns to floats
rows_iter = (
    Table.from_csv("tmp/1.csv", header=True)
    .update(number=c.call_func(count().__next__))
    .update(
        **{column: c.col(column).as_type(float) for column in voltage_columns}
    )
    .into_iter_rows(dict)
)


bad_datetime_to_flags = (
    c.aggregate(
        {
            # per-column array_agg, storing rows with voltage < 10
            column: c.ReduceFuncs.Array(
                c.this, where=c.item(column) < 10
            ).and_then(
                # sliding window of width 3, checking first and last element
                # numbers
                c.iter_windows(width=3)
                .iter(
                    c.iter(c.item("dateTime")),
                    where=c.item(-1, "number") - c.item(0, "number") == 2,
                )
                .flatten()
                .as_type(set)
            )
            for column in voltage_columns
        }
    )
    .call_method("items")
    # flattening dict (column-to-list-of-dates) to column-date pairs
    .iter(c.zip(c.repeat(c.item(0)), c.item(1)), where=c.item(1))
    .flatten()
    # aggregating by dates with array agg to columns
    .pipe(c.aggregate(c.ReduceFuncs.DictArrayDistinct(c.item(1), c.item(0))))
    .execute(rows_iter)
)

# In [38]: bad_datetime_to_flags
# Out[38]:
# {'26/07/2022 14:58:22': ['V94', 'V78'],
#  '26/07/2022 14:58:12': ['V94', 'V78'],
#  '26/07/2022 14:58:02': ['V94', 'V78'],
#  '26/07/2022 14:58:42': ['V78'],
#  '26/07/2022 14:58:32': ['V78']}

(
    Table.from_csv("tmp/1.csv", header=True)
    .update(
        flags=(
            c.naive(bad_datetime_to_flags)
            .item(c.col("dateTime"), default="")
            .and_then(c.this.pipe(" ".join))
        )
    )
    .into_csv("tmp/results.csv")
)
```

The resulting `tmp/results.csv` contains:

```
dateTime,V73,V94,V78,V3,flags
26/07/2022 14:58:02,10.784,9.218,6.702,18.856,V94 V78
26/07/2022 14:58:12,17.432,9.104,7.704,18.530,V94 V78
26/07/2022 14:58:22,17.374,9.846,9.178,18.498,V94 V78
26/07/2022 14:58:32,17.232,17.354,8.188,18.494,V78
26/07/2022 14:58:42,17.066,18.284,9.920,18.216,V78
27/07/2022 16:15:00,17.990,17.698,17.092,19.036,
27/07/2022 16:15:10,17.076,17.262,17.426,18.158,
27/07/2022 16:15:20,17.168,17.774,17.832,19.186,
27/07/2022 16:15:30,17.712,17.522,17.658,18.702,
27/07/2022 16:15:40,17.272,17.532,17.554,18.386,
```